# MySQL won't open in Windows after i edit my.ini

Tags: mysql, windows

My MySQL(ver. 8.0) not support Federated, so i stop the MySQL Services and add federated after [mysqld] in my.ini file. But when i restart the MySQL Service it shows "The mysql service on local computer started and then stopped. some services stop automatically" and when i trying to open MySQL Command Line, it won't open. Help

*Already checked my error log file, and this is what inside:

> 2020-06-09T12:30:57.450365Z 0 [Warning] [MY-010915] [Server]
>   'NO_ZERO_DATE', 'NO_ZERO_IN_DATE' and 'ERROR_FOR_DIVISION_BY_ZERO' sql
>   modes should be used with strict mode. They will be merged with strict
>   mode in a future release.
>
> 2020-06-09T12:30:57.533880Z 0 [System] [MY-010116] [Server] C:\Program
>   Files\MySQL\MySQL Server 8.0\bin\mysqld.exe (mysqld 8.0.20) starting
>   as process 8568
>
> 2020-06-09T12:30:57.810033Z 1 [System] [MY-013576] [InnoDB] InnoDB
>   initialization has started.
>
> 2020-06-09T12:31:07.817948Z 1 [System] [MY-013577] [InnoDB] InnoDB
>   initialization has ended
>
> 2020-06-09T12:31:11.919365Z 0 [System] [MY-011323] [Server] X Plugin
>   ready for connections. Bind-address: '::' port: 33060
>   2020-06-09T12:31:16.948924Z 0 [Warning] [MY-010068] [Server] CA
>   certificate ca.pem is self signed.
>
> 2020-06-09T12:31:17.764039Z 0 [System] [MY-010931] [Server] C:\Program
>   Files\MySQL\MySQL Server 8.0\bin\mysqld.exe: ready for connections.
>   Version: '8.0.20'  socket: ''  port: 3306  MySQL Community Server -
>   GPL.
>
> 2020-06-09T12:35:24.375390Z 0 [System] [MY-013105] [Server] C:\Program
>   Files\MySQL\MySQL Server 8.0\bin\mysqld.exe: Normal shutdown.
>
> 2020-06-09T12:35:26.691671Z 0 [System] [MY-010910] [Server] C:\Program
>   Files\MySQL\MySQL Server 8.0\bin\mysqld.exe: Shutdown complete (mysqld
>   8.0.20)  MySQL Community Server - GPL.

i think there is nothing wrong with it

Comment: run `eventvwr` or "Event Viewer" to get detailed analysis of the error.

Comment: already open event viewer, but how to know the error for mysql?

Comment: Check your `my.ini` with `mysqld --validate-config=ON` o see https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/server-options.html#option_mysqld_validate-config

Comment: nothing happens

Comment: Run `SHOW VARIABLES LIKE 'datadir'` to find out where MySQL stores its data in your PC and then open that directory in Windows explorer to have a look at the log files.

Comment: i try to open mysql via cmd and it shows: Can't connect to MySQL server on 'localhost' (10061), i think this is why i cant open my MySQL Command Line

Comment: Not sure why you're surprised that MySQL service isn't running since you said, right in the question, that it tries to start but then stops. You won't have any clue of the reason if you don't inspect the log files.

Comment: already checked my error log file. Please check my quetion, i have updated it with content of the error log file

Comment: Strange. That looks like a totally normal shutdown. Sorry, I'm clueless.

Comment: right, that's what i mean

Answer (score 1):

Even though this is an older thread. Had the same issue and in my case it appeared to be wrong encoding (UTF8-BOM instead of UTF8)

Found my help at [this SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55952256/474535)